# jquery question, how can i make it calc. multi. form with different form IDs?

Tags: jquery

jq question again, i've 4 form in one page and a script for calc. their total,

how can i calc different total amount with the < form id="#" > things ?

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var total = 0;
        function calcTotal() {
            $("input:checked").each(function() {
            var value = $(this).attr("value");
            total += parseInt(value); 
            });
        }

    //This happens when the page loads
    calcTotal();    
    $("h2").after('<p class="total">Total： <strong>¥' + total + '</strong></p>');
    $("input:checkbox, input:radio").click(function()
    {
        total = 0;
        calcTotal();
        $("p.total").hide().html("Total： <strong>¥" + total + "</strong>").fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `.attr("value")` but `.val()` to retrieve the value of a form element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each form a different id (e.g. ) and then modify you selector to include the form's ID:

```
$('#form1 input:checked').each(function() {
```

UPDATE: You could definitely accomplish this by scoping with an id on each form, but another way is using scoped selectors. (I'm assuming that your <h2> is contained within the form.)

```
$("h2").after('<p class="total">Total： <strong>¥0</strong></p>');
$("input:checkbox, input:radio").click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    var scope = $(this).parent('form');
    $("input:checked", scope).each(function() {
        var value = $(this).attr("value");
        total += parseInt(value, 10);
    });
    $("p.total", scope).hide().html("Total： <strong>¥" + total + "</strong>").fadeIn('slow');
});
```

You can see this in action at http://jsfiddle.net/7NGHq/.

Comment: do i need four function for each form ? ive fail for this :(

Comment: it dont work for me, i have made a big script for it work, thanks for your help btw!

Comment: If you're having problems getting it working, check out the jsFiddle that I linked to. That has a working example with the above code. I would check that your HTML structure is the same as in the example that I give. If not, either tweak your HTML structure or the jQuery code as appropriate.

Comment: i made them the same, but the total amount wasnt updating